# From Objective C call C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

i have problem with calling some function in c++ from objective-c.
I have the following code. In "objCFuncA" how do i call "funcBCallback(std::string inText)" function?. Thanks

**SampleCallback.h**

```
class SampleCallback
{
public:
    static void funcA();
    static void funcBCallback(std::string inText);
};
```

**SampleCallback.mm**

```
void SampleCallback::funcA()
{
    [[SampleCallback_iOS shared] objCFuncA:"My text from C++"];
}

void SampleCallback::funcBCallback(std::string inText)
{
    NSLog(@"SUCCES GET RETURN");
}
```

**SampleCallback_iOS.h**

```
@interface SampleCallback_iOS : NSObject

+ (SampleCallback_iOS*)shared;

- (void)objCFuncA:(const char*)inString;

@end
```

**SampleCallback_iOS.m**

```
@implementation SampleCallback_iOS

static SampleCallback_iOS* instance = nil;

+ (SampleCallback_iOS*)shared
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

- (void)objCFuncA:(const char*)inString
{
    NSLog(@"Text from C++: %s", inString);

    // How to call SampleCallback::funcBCallback?
}
@end
```

Comment: You have to rename the SampleCallback_iOS.m to .mm and use `#include"SampleCallback.h"`, After that is just as simple as `SampleCallback::funcBCallback("your text");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to call C++ functions from plain Objective-C (like you can't call C++ from plain C).

You can convert your Objective-C file to Objective-C++, though. To do so, just rename the file to use the extension `.mm` instead of `.m`.